# Why do I need to run nuget restore before running dotnet restore?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, nuget

I have nuget setup with my private nuget repos.

But when I run dotnet restore it fails saying it can't find my private packages.

If I run nuget restore first then dotnet restore after that it works but dotnet restore should just be using my nuget config to find my sources.

Comment: there is an issue about this. It is old but It may work https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/7875